# Why can't the logstash syslog_pri filter see the priority in syslog messages

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, logstash

I'm running LS 2.0.0, and I've noticed an issue where the syslog_pri filter doesn't detect the priority at the start of my syslogs. My filter config is as follows:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "relp" {
    syslog_pri { }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}(?:%{POSINT} |-)+(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog5424_ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:syslog5424_host}|-) +(-|%{SYSLOG5424PRINTASCII:syslog5424_app}) +%{GREEDYDATA:syslog5424_msg}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{syslog5424_host}" ]
      tag_on_failure => "gpf_relp"
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog5424_ts", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should be able to pull the PRI from the following logs, but it fails, and reverts to the default (13) priority for all messages:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.11.10",
  "_type": "relp",
  "_id": "AVDxXHq4lzuNTbjDHPbE",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "<86>1 2015-11-10T12:26:20.429088+00:00 integration-gw3 sshd 2587 - -  pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser\n",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-10T12:26:20.429Z",
    "type": "relp",
    "host": "10.10.11.23:39532",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice",
    "syslog5424_pri": "86",
    "syslog5424_ts": "2015-11-10T12:26:20.429088+00:00",
    "syslog5424_host": "integration-gw3",
    "syslog5424_app": "sshd",
    "syslog5424_msg": "2587 - -  pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser\n",
    "received_at": "2015-11-10T12:26:20.430Z",
    "received_from": "integration-gw3"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1447158380429
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1447158380429
  ]
}
```

As you can see the PRI is set to 86, and my grok filter picks this up, but the syslog_pri doesn't change these values from default:

```
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice",
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of input are you using?

Comment: I'm using the relp input, but as far as I understand it, this should have no effect on how the filter behaves. If I'm wrong please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-syslog_pri.html) for the `syslog_pri` filter, it seems it's looking for the priority in a field called `syslog_pri`, as opposed to the raw message.

Given that you're running that filter before groking the line, it doesn't have anything in that field and as such is returning priority 13 (user.notice), as outlined in the docs above.

For it to work the way you want, you'll need to move the `syslog_pri` filter *after* the grok and change it to this:

```
syslog_pri { 
  syslog_pri_field_name => "syslog5424_pri"
}
```

Comment: Just figured this out myself, couldn't see this in the docs, d'oh! Thanks