# Logstash filter: syslog_pri always defaulting to notice?

Tags: logging, syslog, logstash, filter, elk

I'm looking through some syslog logs files in my ELK stack and noticed that all the syslog_severity fields are 'notice', when I can verify in the log files that they are not 'notice'. Seems like Logstash is defaulting syslog_severity to notice. I have this in my logstash filter configuration:

```
filter {
 if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "<%{NONNEGINT:syslog_pri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }

    syslog_pri { }

    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at the solution mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/735230/why-cant-the-logstash-syslog-pri-filter-see-the-priority-in-syslog-messages) but don't think that applies in my case, if you look at my filter config file. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parsing-syslog-entries/24653/5) and restarted my logstash service with

```
sudo service logstash restart
```

I've also tried restarting the rest of the services in my ELK stack, still getting notice for all of my syslog_severity fields. Any idea what needs to be changed in the filter?

My log messages are of this format:

```
<134>1 2015-01-01T11:12:23.180242-02:00 message
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your grok pattern and the log line format don't match up. I get a `_grokparsefailure` when trying it in the [grokdebugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). Second, all your events are tagged with `notice` level because that's the default for the `syslog_pri` filter when no `syslog_pri` field exists in the event, as outlined in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-syslog_pri.html).