# Logstash syslog filter not applying to logs?

Tags: syslog, logstash, filter, elk, grok

I'm looking through some syslog logs files in my ELK stack and noticed that all the syslog_severity fields are 'notice', when I can verify in the log files that they are not 'notice'. Seems like Logstash is defaulting syslog_severity to notice. Whenever I go to kibana to search, no matter what I put in the logstash filter configuration file, kibana always returns notice for the severity. I have this in my logstash filter configuration:

```
filter {
 if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424LINE}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri {
      syslog_pri_field_name => "syslog5424_pri"
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog5424_ts", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at the solution mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/735230/why-cant-the-logstash-syslog-pri-filter-see-the-priority-in-syslog-messages) but don't think that applies in my case, if you look at my filter config file. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parsing-syslog-entries/24653/5) and restarted my logstash service with

```
sudo service logstash restart
```

I've also tried restarting the rest of the services in my ELK stack, still getting notice for all of my syslog_severity fields. Any idea what needs to be changed in the filter?

My log messages are of this format:

```
<134>1 2015-01-01T11:12:23.180242-02:00 message
```

I've tested this grok with my messages in the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and it parses my messages just fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you opened another question with essentially the same issues as your previous one? You could have just edited that one to include your changes.